# How to add a link to a file in visual studio using EnvDTE

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am writing a custom scaffolder for our project. And this scaffolder should add links to DTO declarations for client side app.

I have a possibility to retrieve an instance of project item,

```
$folder = Get-ProjectFolder "Views\Shared"
```

and I already found that it is possible to add links using ProjectNode.AddNewFileNodeToHierarchy(string, string) method.

I can get a reference to the DTE service by simply accessing `$DTE` variable predefined in PowerConsole.

The question is how to get instance of ProjectNode I am interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was easier than I thought.

Here is a snippet I finished with:

```
$targetFolder = Get-ProjectFolder "Services" -Project "ServiceModel.Silverlight"
$sourceFile = Get-ProjectItem $ServiceInterfaceOutputPath -Project "ServiceModel"
$sourceFile.Open()
$targetFolder.AddFromFile($($sourceFile.Document.FullName))
```

In case you are not working with t4 scaffolder, this link can be helpfull : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/thread/168d23c8-eee8-4486-a412-147b67673593